# list::sort using operator() c++ short code

Tags: c++, list, sorting, pointers, operators

I'm trying to sort a list of pointers using operator(). it seems like it does the right comparisons, just never actually sorting my list..
here's my classifying class:

```
class Classifier {
public:
    friend bool ClassifyById::operator()(Worker* a, Worker* b);

    void Classifier::classify(list<Worker*> toClassify, int method)
    {
        ClassifyById comparer;
        toClassify.sort(comparer);
    }
};
```

my class which has operator() is:

```
class ClassifyById {
public:
    bool ClassifyById::operator()(Worker* a, Worker* b)
    {
        return (a->getId() < b->getId());
    }
};
```

now given the list of workers with ids inserted in this order:

```
99 11 80 100
```

I tried printing their ids inside the operator() (so you guys can actually kind of debug it) , where comparisons actually happens, and it gave me the output:

```
11 99
100 80
80 11
80 99
100 99
```

but finally, when i printed the list AFTER the sorting, it gave me the order of inserting them, meaning

```
99 11 80 100
```

so it never actually sorted the list, just compared its Id values.. 
HELP..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the list by reference:

```
Classifier::classify(list<Worker*> &toClassify, int method)
```

That's it. You don't want to be creating a copy of the list passed as the argument and sorting that. The changes won't reflect on the passed list.

Comment: I can't even find a QA that would explain the difference. Find a book, whatever.